Liquid syntax error: was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/
I am getting this error when trying to use a regex that has a closing parenthesis.
Liquid::Template.parse("{{ str | regex: 'any regex with }'  }}")

=>
Liquid::SyntaxError: Liquid syntax error: Variable '{{ str | regex: 'any regex with }' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/

Did anybody find a way to escape closing parenthesis?

You need to use Liquid variables to be able to do what you want:

Create variable that will store } symbol
Create variable that will store your regex
Use the second variable as your filter variable

Here is the example of how it could look:
template = "{% capture bracket_sign %}{% raw %}}}{% endraw %}{% endcapture %}"
template += "{% capture my_regex %}any regex with {{bracket_sign}}{% endcapture %}"
template += "{{str | regex: my_regex }}"
Liquid::Template.parse(template)

